# SQL - Creating Database and Querying it

Tags: sql, database

I need to answer the following instructions and am wondering if I'm on the right path as far as answering it.

**Instructions**

Design a database for the following scenario: You need to track all of the dogs at an agility competition.
They have different events for each competition and each dog has a score from each event.
Also, write the SQL queries to return all the dogs in the competition, the events that each dog are enrolled in, and the score that they received in that event.

```
CREATE DATABASE Competition (
  Dogs CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  Score INT NOT NULL,
  Event CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
)

SELECT * 
FROM Competition
```

This seems to be a little too simple, but would this satisfy all the instructions that's given?

**EDIT**

Would this solution work?

```
CREATE TABLE Dogs (
   Name STRING,
   EventId INT
)
CREATE TABLE Events (
   Name STRING,
   Id INT
)
CREATE TABLE Scores (
   Score INT,
   EventId INT
)
SELECT name
FROM Dogs 
INNER JOIN Events On Events.Id = Dogs.EventId
INNER JOIN Scores On Events.Id = Scores.Event.Id
```

Answer (score 2):

You have your entities mixed up in the syntax. The database is the logical container, within it you create your tables.
For example, if you are using T-SQL:

```
CREATE DATABASE DogCompetition;
USE DogCompetition;
CREATE TABLE Dogs 
(Dog VARCHAR(30) PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE Events 
(Event VARCHAR(30) PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE DogEventScores 
(Dog VARCHAR(30) REFERENCES Dogs(Dog), 
Event VARCHAR(30) REFERENCES Events (Event),
Score INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Dog, Event)
);
INSERT INTO Dogs (Dog) VALUES ('Charlie');
INSERT INTO Events (Event) VALUES ('Running');
INSERT INTO DogEventScores (Dog, Event, Score) VALUES ('Charlie', 'Running', 8);
SELECT * FROM DogEventScores;
```

HTH

Comment: Appreciate the answer, im just looking for regular SQL syntax. I was told that for my purposes, just using `CREATE TABLE` .... and going from there would at least start the database making process and can go from there. Is that right?

Comment: Sure. that means you will be creating the tables in whatever default database your client connects to... What database engine are you using?

Comment: I'm not using any db engine, this is just a practice problem that was given to me

Comment: Just ignore the first 2 lines then and start with the 'create table'.

Comment: Ah icic, but to be thorough with the question, it wouldn't hurt to use those first two lines either right?

Comment: Probably, the USE command is T-SQL specific, not ANSI SQL.
If I were your teacher I wouldn't deduct from your score because of it, unless you were explicitly told to use only ANSI compliant syntax.

Comment: Ah so just regular SQL, i can start with `CREATE TABLE` right off the bat and skip the `CREATE DATABASE` then?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.

Answer (score 1):

You should design your table like below.

Dog and Competition has many to many relationship and Event is the mediator table.

```
Dog (DogId, DogName)

Event(DogId, CompetitionId, EventName, Score)

Competition(CompetitionId, Name)
```

Queries to return all the dogs in the competition // return all dog for competition id equal 1

```
select * from Dog inner join Event on Dog.DogId = Event.DogId where Event.CompetitionId = 1
```

The events that each dog are enrolled in, and the score that they received in that event.

```
   select Event.EventName, sum(Score) from Dog inner join Event on Dog.DogId = Event.DogId 
where Dog.DogName = 'Misa' group by Event.EventName
```

Comment: Appreciate the help. So, I would start with `CREATE TABLE` first and then add your suggestions accordingly right?

Comment: yes, you create table, insert some data and run queries

Comment: Do i need to add the CREATE DATABASE first?

Comment: yes, create database YourDB; use YourDB; create table Dog (..)

Comment: ok, im confused by why you have the Event table and inside of it you have `CompetitionId` in there

Comment: also could we not return all dogs in the competition, the events they're enrolled in, and the score all in one shot?